# How to assign a character to a class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

In Python, the builtin classes have alias-like things.

The `str` class can be used as:
`print(str("hi"))`,
but there is an alias so you can just use:
`print("hi")`.

There is also an alias for `dict`:
You can use `dict()` or `{}`.

I have my own class, `myClass()`

I can call it using `myClass(a=1,b=2)`, but I want to be able to use it like:
`- a=1, b=2 -`
or

```
-
a=1,
b=2
-
```

The character doesn't need to be `-`, I just chose it as an example.

My class can accept any number of arguments, so if it is possible I want to also be able to make an empty *myClass* like this: `--`

and the ability for it to take as many args as needed:

```
-
a=1,
b=2,
c=3,
d=4,
e=5,
...
-
```

Comment: No, Python doesn't allow you to invent your own syntax like that.

Comment: Your "alias" is a [*literal*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals), and you can't define your own without modifying the interpreter itself. Also note that your use of `str` *also* involves a string literal.

Comment: Sorta related: [Can you add new statements to Python's syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/214881/4518341)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making your own statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222843/making-your-own-statements) - it's about statements (keywords), but 90% of the same rules apply to special character tokens.

Comment: The "alias" for `dict` is not an alias. Try `dict({'x': 'y'})` vs `{{'x': 'y'}}`.

Comment: These things *are not aliases at all*. In some cases, you are talking about literals, which **are not equivalent to the type constructors at all* and certainly not aliases. Also, `print(str(x))` is not an alias for `print(x)`. And `dict` is not an alias for `dict()`, this is just fundamentally confused. One merely is a reference to the class object, the other is calling the class  constructor